# Is there a name for separating two items with comma when listing them?

Tags: commas, proper-nouns, titles, journalism

I noticed that journalists often write titles in which they connect two proper nouns (but not only those) with a comma, instead of using "and".

Two examples:

- [Poll shows gap between **Le Pen, Macron** as turnout is seen at historic low](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/poll-shows-gap-between-le-pen-macron-abstention-is-seen-historic-low-2022-04-12/)
- [Cubans seek refuge in **Greece, Italy** amid **economic, political** crisis](https://associatestimes.com/cubans-seek-refuge-in-greece-italy-amid-economic-political-crisis/amp/)

Is this grammatically correct? Is there a name for such a writing style? Is the main reason here shortening the title?

Comment: Headlines are not subject to ordinary grammar rules. They often omit necessary but predictable words. Sometimes reading them is very very difficult, especially headlines about sports or politics or sex, which are full of taboos and specialized terms.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Journalistic Comma

*Journalistic Comma* is as close to a name as one will likely find. Those of us in Journalism use the comma as the OP describes simply to save space in a headline by not writing "and."

Comment: Searching the term "Journalistic Comma" online doesn't bring up much, so I conclude there is no widely used name. The answer is still good since it's aware of this fact and it also addresses the second part of the question.

Comment: I've only found this used as a rare synonym for the fixed phrase 'serial comma' or 'Oxford comma'. OP asks about the practice of replacing the word 'and' in a coordinate noun phrase (two NPs joined by 'and') with a comma. Serial commas are possible only with lists of 3 or more elements (Harpo, Groucho[,] and Chico).